# How to I add the Caller Name in an SMS Body in Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio

I'm building an automated information line for realtors. In the Message body, I need to send a lead notification from the caller. What's the function to retrieve the caller's name?

I have Caller Name Lookup enabled on the active phone line and says I can pass the data as the CallerName parameter in requests.

When I put `{{trigger.call.From}}` in the message body, it just displays the phone number and not the name.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is

> {{trigger.call.CallerName}}

You can look at the Twilio Studio Execution logs, click on the execution SID (starts with FN...), the trigger widget, Widget & Flow Properties, and then you will see all the execution metadata available to you and how to access it from within your Studio Flow.